# how to access another user1s table in sql developer database?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

`BBMA.SALES_BKP` TABLE IS THERE IN `BBMP SCHEMA`(user)
I WANT TO ACCESS "`SALES_BKP` TABLE" through `DUMMY`(its different user)

Comment: Please be more clear about your query.

Comment: Well - do you have the necessary privileges? Or, to go one step back: do you understand my question about "privileges"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how.

```
SQL> create user dummy identified by dummy
  2    default tablespace user_data
  3    temporary tablespace temp
  4    quota unlimited on user_data;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to dummy;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create user bbma identified by bbma
  2    default tablespace user_data
  3    temporary tablespace temp
  4    quota unlimited on user_data;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to bbma;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now, create table and let another user select from it.

```
SQL> connect dummy/dummy@orcl
Connected.
SQL> create table sales_bkp(id number, value number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into sales_bkp values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> grant select on sales_bkp to bbma;                  --> this

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect bbma/bbma@orcl
Connected.
SQL> select * from dummy.sales_bkp;                      --> note owner name

        ID      VALUE
---------- ----------
         1        100

SQL>
```